# Solspace Super Search - Relevance not working

Tags: solspace

**Sorry - I can't figure out how to answer my own question, but this came down to me not using a Keyword Search. Relevance scoring only works on keyword searches.**

EE 2.7.2
Super Search 2.1.3

Hi

We are trying to implement Relevance within our search results, but having no luck at all. We output {relevance_count} but it always returns 0. Eventually we also want to add relevance_proximity="yes" but we will come back to that.

Here is the code we are using and it still returns a {relevance_count} of 0 even when the title and/or tags is an exact match:

```
{exp:super_search:results
channel="photos"
relevance="title=5+tags=1"}

<h2>{title} - {relevance_count}</h2>
<p>{tags}</p>

{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Copied from above...

"This came down to me not using a Keyword Search. Relevance scoring only works on keyword searches."